# What is the pressure of triple point and melting point for ethyl chloride?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I need the information for pressure of triple point and melting point for ethyl chloride but on the internet I found only information for temperatures which are 134,5K and 134,82K.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: It would seem simple to find on the web... but when I researched the phase diagram and triple point for "chloroethane" and for "ethyl chloride", there seemed no readily availbale answer. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53280/equation-to-calculate-the-triple-point points to a *theoretical* calculation, and there are paywalled references, e.g., https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4615-2522-6_231,